# Read extended image properties from jpg file

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, exif, system.io.file

I want to read Attributes of a jpg file.
Following is what I have done so far but I am not able to get attribute "A" as shown in the image. All I get from below function is list of strings with ASCII & numerical values.

```
    static void ReadProperties(Image imgImage)
    {
        var listImageProperties =new List<string>();
        try
        {
            PropertyItem[] propItems = imgImage.PropertyItems;

            foreach (PropertyItem propItem in propItems)
            {
                listImageProperties.Add("0x" + propItem.Id.ToString("x"));
                listImageProperties.Add(propItem.Type.ToString());
                listImageProperties.Add(propItem.Len.ToString());
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Note that the 'attributes' are a file system concept and nothing to do with Exif. If you want to read Exif information from an image as well, take a look at my [metadata-extractor](https://github.com/drewnoakes/metadata-extractor-dotnet) library which will read all sorts of metadata from your image and video files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer after a bit of debugging.
Following code reads the file attribute.

```
var info = new FileInfo(path);
var att= info.Attributes;//Attributes are enum for ReadOnly, Archive... & so on.
```